# Functions inside Loops Python

Tags: python, function, loops

Is it in general a good idea to place multiple functions inside one loop just to spare some work with giving arguments to the functions?

example:

```
for elem1 in mylist:
    def function1():
        for elem2 in elem1
    function1()
```

rather than:

```
def function1(elem1):
    for elem2 in elem1

for elem1 in mylist:
    function1(elem1)
```

I know this looks silly, but its quite important part of my work.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Why would you define a function inside a `for` loop? That's... Interesting.

Comment: Unless you have some glaring need, you very likely should _not_ do what you are doing in the first sample.

Comment: This seems like more of an architecture issue than anything else. Why do you need that closure?

Comment: Can I ask why is it important part of your work? putting a function definition inside of a for loop to save the hassle of passing a variable?

Comment: When you say that you're trying to *"spare some work"* do you mean spare resources in the script or something else?

Comment: Did you actually try to run either of those code samples?

Comment: I am working in a massive nest of if-s and for-s, where some things has to run multiple times at various places. I needed functions to save writing and be able to call them wherever they are needed. Since functions are not aware of the local variables within the loops when they are called I'll have to add args to functions which is a bit of extra work :)
I only needed a more professional opinion and now its done :) Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't find the question unclear at all. What I don't understand is why people feel compelled to ask the OP why they're asking. A perfectly reasonable answer is given by @gerosalesc below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid defining a function inside a loop, whatever you are doing try to define this function in a higher level so that you reuse them in as many places in your code as required. Defining a function inside a loop is adding unnecessary steps and will certainly affect performance.